# how to record Our Activity in Android Without Root with Ice Cream Sandwich Android?

Tags: android, video, video-capture, video-processing, projection

I want to record my Activity  in A Video file in android version 15+ so please Help.I try The SYSTEM_PROJECTION_SERVICE BUT THIS service only works in version 21+ and i want to version 15 to 22 all Version Activity  Record In a Video?